# How can i delete between these tags <value></value>

Tags: c#, tags

I have asked this question and didn't come right. I want to delete the output between the value tags but am falling to do so. i only want to delete the value tag that is within the data which is my table. can you please help me delete those values. keep it in mind that those output are not hard-coded,the user just entered those values, so every time i load the form i want to delete those output between the tags.

```
 <data name="CurrentSelectedUser_Label" xml:space="preserve"> 
   <value>Current selected record:</value> 
   <comment>[Font]Bold[/Font][DateStamp]2015/01/01 00:00:00[/DateStamp][Comment] this is a comment.!![/Comment]</comment> 
 </data> 
 <data name="FinEnrolment_Exit_Button" xml:space="preserve"> 
   <value>Exit Finger Enrolment</value> 
   <comment>[Font]Regular[/Font][DateStamp]2014/012/01 00:00:00[/DateStamp]  [Comment] this is a comment.!![/Comment]</comment> 
  </data>
```

i tried this, but am failing to specify the value tags that are within the data which is my table. see my coding below;

```
    string text = File.ReadAllText(outputFilePath); 
    text = DeleteBetween1(text, "<value>", "</value>"); 

     public string DeleteBetween1(string STR, string FirstString, string LastString)
    {
        string regularExpressionPattern1 = "<value(.*?)</value>";
        Regex regex = new Regex(regularExpressionPattern1, RegexOptions.Singleline);
        MatchCollection collection = regex.Matches(STR.ToString());
        var val = string.Empty;
        foreach (Match m in collection)
        {
            val = m.Groups[1].Value;
            STR = STR.Replace(val, "");
        }
        STR = STR.Replace(val, "");
        return STR;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Linq to XML

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

        foreach(var valueNode in doc.Descendants("data").SelectMany(n=> n.Elements("value")))
        {
            valueNode.Value = string.Empty;
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this and it is returning all the value tags. i only want the value tags within my table "data" as you can see

                                                                                                                Regex regex = new Regex(String.Format(@"(?<=<value>).*?(?=</value>)", FirstString, LastString));

Comment: the table name is "data" i wont to delete the values within the data table, look at my xml code

Comment: I have valid xml.
 XmlDocument _doc = new XmlDocument();
                _doc.Load(outputFilePath); //filename
                string xmlcontents = _doc.InnerXml;

Comment: your method delete even the tags, i want to delete what is in between the tags

Comment: for me it deleted the tags. i am using linq method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71094/discussion-between-florian-schmidinger-and-it-forward).

Comment: Am trying to login into a chat but it keeps on taking me back to my question. Can we use an email

Comment: Would you mind if we can continue in the  next 25 minutes?  Please I really need your help as am stack for days

Comment: Thanks, will be in touch with you soon

Comment: Are you there?  We can continue now

Comment: this does not take into account there may be value tags elsewhere in the document

Comment: @krystanhonour Actually does... i had a longer chat with the op yesterday

Comment: @krystanhonour but you are right if you took that regex part of the answer which i just removed.

Comment: yup that's much better and is equivalent pretty much to what I wrote :)

Answer (score 1):

Appologies for the previous answer I've knocked up a test program in linqpad which acheives what you want.
Hopefully this approach should work for you.

I've had to insert a root node or the XML will not parse, I called this root.

```
void Main()
{ 
    string xml = @"
    <root>
    <data name=""CurrentSelectedUser_Label"" xml:space=""preserve""> 
       <value>Current selected record:</value> 
       <comment>[Font]Bold[/Font][DateStamp]2015/01/01 00:00:00[/DateStamp][Comment] this is a comment.!![/Comment]</comment> 
     </data> 
     <data name=""FinEnrolment_Exit_Button"" xml:space=""preserve""> 
       <value>Exit Finger Enrolment</value> 
       <comment>[Font]Regular[/Font][DateStamp]2014/012/01 00:00:00[/DateStamp]  [Comment] this is a comment.!![/Comment]</comment> 
      </data></root>";

    var doc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xml));

    var nodes = doc.XPathSelectElements("/root/data/value"); 


    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        ((XElement)node).Value = string.Empty;
    }

    ... output the doc here.
}
```

Comment: It is resx file(xml) . can you demonstrate what you talking about,am bit lost